# Expressjs send content after listen

Tags: express

I want to make a route in express js to send some content after 1000 ms.
Note: I cant use res.sendFile, it has to be a plain route.
This is the code for the route:

```js
app.get('/r', (req,res)=>{
    res.send("a")
    setTimeout(()=>{
       res.send("fter")
    }, 1000)
}
app.listen(8080)
```

But I get the error: ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT, 
I assume because the page has already been loaded.
I need my node program to send it after it has already been loaded, 
so I cant like send a html,js,css script to do it. Is it possible? I cant seem to find how.

Well, if that is not possible, what I am really trying to do is after the page has loaded, execute js or send a message that the page can receive from the node program, like if there was res.execute_js('postMessage(1)')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is for all the people wondering. No you cannot do this with pure express (there is a workaround, so keep reading).

The reason you cant do this is because, when the user requests to the url, it sends them a response, and the browser renders it. You cant then tell it to change the response, as the browser has already received a response. Even if you send multiple, like with res.write, rather then res.send, the browser will just wait until it receives all the data.

Here are two workarounds:
    1. Use socket.io, cscnode, or another library to have events for updating text,
    2. Send hardcoded html, that updates text (1 was probably better)

That is all I think you can do.
More clarification on the socketio one is basically have an event for changing text that you can fire from node, and the browser will understand, and change the text.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT based on your edit: So as I understand you want a way to send different values from a node app endpoint without using socketio. I've managed to replicate a similar experimental behavior using readable streams. Starting off, instead of returning response to the request with `res.send()` you should be using `res.write()` In my case I did something like this:

```js
app.post('/api', (req, res) => {
    res.write("First");
    setTimeout(() => {
        res.write("Second");
        res.end();
    }, 1000);
});
```

This will write to a stream "First" then after 1000ms it'll write another "Second" chunk then end the stream, thus completing the POST request.

Now in the client, you'll make the fetch response callback async, get the `ReadableStream` from the request like so

```js
const reader = response.body.getReader();
```

now we should be reading this stream, we'll first initialize an array to collect all what we're reading,

```js
const output = [];
```

now to actually read the stream,

```js
let finished, current;
while (!finished) {
    ({ current, finished} = await reader.read());
    if (finished) break;
    output.push(current);
}
```

if you read current in the loop, it'll contain each value we passed from `res.write()` and it should read twice, "First" and after 1000ms "Second".

EDIT: This is very experimental however, and I wouldn't recommend this in a production codebase. I'd suggest trying out socketio or a publish/subscribe mechanism instead.

Old answer: <s>You're already sending "a" back, you should remove the first `res.send()` invocation at the top of the callback.</s>

Comment: good idea! however, as signified by the second thing it says being fter, and the first being a, I need to send something first, basically I am trying to send a message to the page loaded, but my bad for not explaining it clearly.

Comment: I think you need to provide where you call the endpoint from the client-side, and also rephrase or explain more what you want to do. So far, I understand that when you call your endpoint, it should first return a response to the client that the request has been received, but then again after some delay, return some more response to the client, and tell the client that the request has been fully finished?

Comment: correct, though not really that it has been fully finished, as I am making a client-serverevent system, so in my node app it broadcasts and event, and my route/page recieves it.

Comment: also without socketio

Comment: @sld I edited my answer to try and tackle your edited problem.

Comment: perfect, now I will ask the second part of my question.